# simple cursor adapter column '_id' does not exist

Tags: android, sqlite, xamarin

I have _id set up in the database but when debugging it says the _id does not exist at this line:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter sqldb_adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, Resource.Layout.Recordslayout, sqldb_cursor, from, to);
```

I am using the tutorial from [this blog](http://www.itexico.com/blog/bid/97885/How-to-Create-a-Database-Mobile-App-with-SQLite-and-Xamarin-Studio).

One thing I do not have it set up in my mainactivity but a different one. I have set the public class to the correct activity.

Comment: a cursor adater requires _id column. put some relevant code so that someone can help u better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This occurs when you don't have the `_id` column present in the projection(`String[] from` in your case). Adapter needs this column. Crosscheck that `_id` column is present and add some code if you want further help.